# passport token is not being authorized

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, authorization, passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/User');
const key = require('./keys').secret;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = key;

module.exports = (passport) => {
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    console.log(jwt_payload);
    User.findById(jwt_payload.id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);

        }
    });
}))
}
```

I am using passport-jwt stratergy to validate with token but this is file is not running properly i even tried to console the payload here but this is not even logging it

```
 passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) 
 console.log(jwt_payload);
```

**Token Stratergy**

```
 const payload = {
                    id: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                    name: user.name
                }
                const token = jwt.sign(payload, config.secret, { expiresIn: 36000 });
                return res.json({
                    success: true,
                    token: 'JWT ' + token,
                    user: {
                        id: user.id,
                        name: user.name,
                        username: user.username
                    }
                })
```

*And when i am using this on the protected routes it is not authorizing the protected routes*

**Result = Unauthorized**

```
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
res.send("Profile");
});
```

Comment: Can you show the example of request you are sending to the server?

Comment: I am using postman with Key = Authorization and value = token returned by json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your authentication is not working is that you've used the legacy token prefix "JWT" and a modern JWT (`fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken`) extractor as an option to your strategy.

You can do one of the steps to fix the problem:

1. change the token prefix to `'Bearer ' + token`
2. change the token extractor:

   `opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("JWT");`